# In ExtJS dataview single select mode how can I clear item selection

Tags: extjs4

I want to clear dataview item when it lost focus, mean when user click somewhere else x-item-selected class is removed from current selected item.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use

```
dataview.getSelectionModel().deselectAll();
```

to remove the selection